# Send attachment uploaded by form using PHPMailer

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I want to send an attachement file selected by the user from an html form (a pdf file for example), and send it by email to destination.

I can send every input by mail but the attachement, can you please help, any help appreciated. Here's my code

```
 <label>Mail : </label>
    <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="mail adress">
    <div class="box">

    &nbsp;

    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="inputfile inputfile-5"  />
    </div>
```

And my form-handler.php (I'm uploading just the necessary lines) :

```
<?php

     $file = $_POST['file'];

     $email = $_POST['email'];

    require $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

        $mail = new PHPMailer;

        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;
        $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
        $mail->Host = '*****';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = '****';
        $mail->Password = '****';
        $mail->From = $email;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Port = ****;

        $mail->setFrom('*****', '*****');

        $mail->addAddress('*****', '*****');

        $mail->Subject = utf8_decode("Thank you for signing up");




        $mail->AddAttachment( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name'] );

        $mail->Body = ($file);

        //$mail->AltBody = utf8_decode($file);

        if (!$mail->Send()) {
            echo "error. <p>";
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            exit;
        }

        echo "mail sent";

?>
```

Comment: are you uploading the file? If you echo $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] what's you get?

Comment: I'm getting nothing, blank!! no error!

Comment: Then the file isn't uploading. You have to upload the file and then add the path to the file in attachment

Comment: I agree, but the file is uploaded using the form, I dont know the path

Comment: ok i will make a small scipt to show you how is done just wait 2 minutes.

Comment: You didn't need to go to the effort of asking this question; the send file upload example provided in PHPMailer's examples folder does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Before sending a attachment you need to find where the attachment is. So when you upload the file you can assign it to upload in a particular folder.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"./upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

In this case we have create a "upload" folder in our directory and we save our file in this directory.
After uploading the file we have to save the path in one variable.
This will do the trick.

```
$filename = "./upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

Now we have all what we need and we can send the file as an attachment with email.

```
$mail->AddAttachment($filename);
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped, iv arranged my code, works fine now

Comment: I'am glad to here that :)

Comment: @Coby_131 if the answer fixed your code mark it as solution to your question